# Corporate firewall blocking MP4s is there a way to detect this in php?

Tags: php, firewall, mp4

I have an application that auto-plays MP4s as part of an animated model. Some corporate networks block MP4s and so I'd like to be able to detect if the MP4 is blocked, and if it is, serve up a still image instead. Is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: Why not simply try to download a file of that type from a static known location via http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and if it doesn't work display an image - otherwise move on to the mp4 you meant to show in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As my comment solved the issue, I am posting it so that the question can leave the queue.

While there isn't an inbuilt PHP function that can test a network to see if blocking of this manner is done, a fairly simple workaround would be to simply keep a static tiny file of the type that might be blocked.

During execution of the code, the script can then test ( using fopen for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to see if it can reach/download this file without issue. If this is the case, the script will be able to download the required media and display it to the user without issue. If it is not able to reach the file, then a substitute (like an image) may be used by the code to be displayed for the user.